# Using Robot Framework Ldap Library

Tags: ldap, robotframework

How far has the Robot framework Ldap library implementation gone ?

Can the keywords be used for execution with pybot ?

Updating the question now.

I came across python-ldap and using that for performing an ldapsearch

```
def my_search(l, baseDN, searchScope, searchFilter, retrieveAttributes):
logger.console("Reachedhere")
try:
    logger.console("Reachedhereinsidetry\n")
    ldap_result_id = l.search(baseDN,searchScope,searchFilter,retrieveAttributes)
    logger.console("Gotresult\n")
```

Now I invoked my_search in my Robot testcase. It throws this error

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Robot Testcase excerpt. :

```
${SearchReturn}    my_search    ${ldapObj}    "uid=2343,ds=SU,o=DEFAULT,dc=C-N"    ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL    "objectClass=*"    None
```

There is nothing in integer format here. What could be the issue ?

Any leads on this ?

Comment: what ldap library are you talking about? Have you tried using this library?

Comment: No , I haven't. This is a java based library that I came across. I use a lot of ldap operations and so exploring ways to implement it. This ldaplib seems to be java based implementation. 
Have you tried it ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting seems to me to be a casting error. I.e. something is fed a string, where an integer is expected. This is an easy situation to come in with the Robot Framework script.

In the Robot Framework general documentation the section about [Number Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#number-variables) shows that you can set a variable to an integer via the `${76}`notation. This should happen in the calling keyword or test case.

In case you're unable to do that in the calling keyword, the [BuiltIn library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20Integer) has a [`Convert To Integer`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20Integer) keyword which would then do the conversion for you.

Comment: I have passed the following :

    ${SearchReturn}    my_search    ${ldapObj}    "uid=2341,ds=SU,o=DEFAULT,dc=C-N"    ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL    "objectClass=*"    None

There is no integer in here.

Comment: Can you point us to the library you are using and how it is integrated into your script? It still seems to me that the string you are inputting does not match with what the method in the Library is expecting. I think the method expects an integer.

Comment: I have imported ldap library in the python file. This is the python-ldap library ~ https://www.python-ldap.org/

Comment: Looking at the [Search() documentation](https://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html#ldap.LDAPObject.search), it seems to me that the response is an integer `LDAPObject.search(base, scope[, filterstr='(objectClass=*)'[, attrlist=None[, attrsonly=0]]]) → int` and perhaps in your Python Keyword Library you need to use an Integer Python variable  or cast the output of `search()` to a string before assigning it: `str(search(..))`

Comment: Where can I do this conversion ? And why str () ? I need an integer.